# Gitlab.com Import Failing - Validation failed: Title has already been taken

Tags: gitlab

Import Repository - Validation failed: Title has already been taken

When Importing an export from CE Gitlab (GitLab Community Edition 8.17.2 bab14bd ) the import fails with a

[image]

I have deleted all Issue Labels, and gone through all my issues (by exporting to excel and looking for duplicate titles) and I"m stumped atm.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is related to [issue 20770](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20770)

> I had to delete the new (empty) project to re-start the import.
>
> the problem was effectively a collision in deploy keys.
>
> It's not the first time I had issues with the deploy keys. Trying to import an already present one gives cryptic error.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for offering up this, but this wasn't related.